# Average leaf height in Left Child Right Sibling binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, average

I'm practicing for one exam and I have one example that I can't figure out. Anyway, task goes like this:

> You have a data structure for Left Child Right Sibling tree that looks
>   like this:
>
> ```
> public class TreeLCRSnode {
>     public TreeLCRSnode parent, leftSon, rightSibling;
> }
> ```
>
> You need to write a function named double avgH(TreeLCRSnode root) that
>   will return back the result of average leaf height.

To be sure everyone understand, leaf is a node without any child. So for example, if a tree looks like this,

```
4
|
2----7
|
3
```

then there is two leafs, one at height 1 (no. 7) and one at height 2 (no. 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for this task you are required to use several global variables:

- `currentHeight` - the current height in the recursion
- `leafHeightSum` - the sum of the heights of all the currently found leaves
- `leafNumber` - the count of all found up-to-now leaves

Then the solution can go like this:

```
int currentHeight, leafHeightSum, leafNumber;
double traverse(TreeLCRSnode node) {
    currentHeight = 0;
    leafHeightSum = 0;
    leafNumber = 0;
    traverseHelper(node);
    // if the tree can be empty you might need a check here.
    return (double)leafHeightSum  / (double)leafNumber;
}

void traverseHelper(TreeLCRSnode node) {
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.leftSon) {
            currentHeight++;
            traverseHelper(node.leftSon);
            currentHeight--;
        } else {
            leafHeightSum  += currentHeight;
            leafNumber++;
        }
        node = node.rightSibling;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fine if you ask me. Thank you Boris.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification of [Boris Strandjev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337927/1247955). Its goal is to be a little more succint and to avoid global variables since `currentHeight` is passed by value, `leafNumber` is passed by reference and sum of leaf heights is return value.

```c
double traverse(TreeLCRSnode node) {
    int leafNumber=0;

    return (double)traverseHelper(node,0,&leafNumber)/(double)leafNumber;
}

int traverseHelper(TreeLCRSnode node, int currentHeight, int *leafNumber) {
    if(!node) return 0;

    if(!node.leftSon) {
        (*leafNumber)++;
        return currentHeight + traverse(node.rightSibling, currentHeight, leafNumber);
    } else {
        return traverse(node.leftSon, currentHeight+1, leafNumber) + traverse(node.rightSibling, currentHeight, leafNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write a program that will traverse the tree.  Something like:

```
void traverse(TreeLCRSnode node) {
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.leftSon) traverse(node.leftSon);
        node = node.rightSibling;
    }
}
```

That will get you to all of the nodes.  Then you just need to decide if the node is a leaf, and figure out how to compute the average (hint: pass around a depth, keep track of the sum of depths of leaves found so far, and the total # of leaves found so far).

Comment: I've made this before already but I still have no idea how to go forward. How to detect at which level I am, how to count all the levels and how to count all the leafs?
Especially when I can send only one parameter to a recursive function.